# gnome 3 resolution change delay too short

Tags: ubuntu, gnome3

How can I increase this delay to allow my monitors to display the selected settings before reverting?

When changing my screen resolution using the displays dialog, my monitors stay blank longer than the confirmation dialog asking to confirm. FC, what do?

The resolutions all work fine. It just takes too long for my display to flip modes or whatever it does. They do this on Windows and Linux. For instance, I have never seen the BIOS POST screen due to the time needed for my displays to sync.

Comment: What brand and model are your monitors?

Comment: Not that it helps answer my question, but they are 3x Acer GD235HZs through a triple Startech displayport splitter (adds more delay and issues) and an LG 24UD58-B on HDMI

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and not found how to increase the delay, yet I found a workaround by pressing [ENTER] multiple times during the switch process.
Of course it may be a bit risky if you are not sure of the final result.